# SSJS redirect error 500

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, redirect

I'm using a simple SSJS code to redirect according to an API call results. But I keep getting error 500.

Problematic code:

```
if(ContactId == 'null'){
    var errorURL = 'https://errorURL.com'
    Redirect(errorURL,false);
}
```

When I remove the `Redirect(errorURL,false);` there is no error.

I even tried to copy this one from the MC example document:

```
Redirect("http://example.com/index.html",false);
```

And I still get an error.

Full code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

    var RowCountFlag = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@RowCountFlag");

    if (RowCountFlag == 0) {

        var firstName = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@firstName");
        var lastName = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@lastName");
        var email = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@email");

        try {
           var url = 'https://test33333?timeout=60';
            var contentType = 'application/json';
            var headerNames = ["Username", "Token"];
            var headerValues = ["YYYYYYYYYYYYY", "XXXXXXXXXXXXxx"];

            var payloadObj = {
            "parameters":
                [
                    {"Key": "Acc_firstName",   "Value": firstName},
                    {"Key": "Acc_lastName",  "Value": lastName},
                    {"Key": "emal",    "Value": email},          
                ]
            }

            var OptInDE = DataExtension.Init("my de");
            var errorURL = 'www.erorURL.com'
            var payloadString = Platform.Function.Stringify(payloadObj);
            var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payloadString, headerNames, headerValues);
            if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
                Variable.SetValue("@APIflag", '200')
                var responseStr = Stringify(result.Response[0])
                var cleanResponseStr = responseStr.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
                var starts = 9 + cleanResponseStr.lastIndexOf("ContactId")
                var ends = cleanResponseStr.indexOf("AssetId")
                var ContactId = cleanResponseStr.slice(starts,ends)
                Variable.SetValue("@ContactId", ContactId)
                var rows = Platform.Function.InsertDE("my de",["Serial Number","Resquest","Respond", "ContactId"],[SN,Stringify(payloadObj),Stringify(result),ContactId]);

                if(ContactId == 'null'){
                    var errorURL = 'https://errorURL.com'
                    Redirect(errorURL,false);
                }
            } else {
                var rows = Platform.Function.InsertDE("my de",["Serial Number","Resquest","Respond"],[SN,Stringify(payloadObj),Stringify(result)]);
                Redirect(errorURL, false);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            var rows = Platform.Function.InsertDE("Name_Your_Dolphin_IConduct_Log",["Serial Number","Resquest","Respond"],[SN,Stringify(payloadObj),Stringify(result)]);
            Write(Stringify("Err at API call: "+e));
            Redirect(errorURL, false);
        }
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: if you put a try/catch block around the redirect, what error is returned?

Comment: Why are you writing output to the page and immediately redirecting?  Might be easier to troubleshoot if you set some flags on error conditions and redirect at the end if the flag is set -- that way you can easily disable the redirect to view the output when debugging.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - I indeed think the issue is with including text output before the Redirect call - as I explain in my updated answer.

Comment: If you notice, the URL you have in the If(ContactId...) is different than what is set as default above that. Could the url be malformed or relative instead of absolute? (Also as you have it in this example, I think the default one would fail as it needs the protocol in order to work)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers. I have made a lot of changes, and this actually works now, and I'm not really sure why...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set a semicolon in the line, where you define *errorURL*:

```
if(ContactId == 'null'){
    var errorURL = 'https://errorURL.com';
    Redirect(errorURL,false);
}
```

Also, I will suggest to do this test in a slightly better way, to ensure it actually does what you expect. In this case, it actually checks if your contact ID has the string value of 'null'. I expect this is what you need instead:

```
if(ContactId == null || ContactId == ''){
    var errorURL = 'https://errorURL.com';
    Redirect(errorURL,false);
}
```

Another reason for the error (which is more plausible in your case) is printing any output before the `Redirect` function. As the redirect function alters the header of the Cloud Page (responding with code [302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) and the destination URL set in the `Location` header), outputting anything prior to the `Redirect` function results in an error, as the headers are set on the first line of code with output in it (e.g. utilising `Write` function).

So remove any usage of `Write` in your SSJS which might interfere with your `Redirect`, and also ensure no output is generated above the opening `<script>` tag.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. actually i don't think you really need semicolon.

Comment: @yoni349 - updated with what I think is more plausible cause of your error

Comment: Did my latest suggestion help you, @yoni349?

Comment: It actually worked without removing the "write". So guess that wasn't the issue here. really appreciate your help though. By the time to got the see your inputs i made so many changes and lost track about what actually made it work. I think it got to do with MC executing the catch even though there are not any errors. As mentioned here https://www.howtosfmc.com/posts/the-catches-of-try-catch-in-sfmc-ssjs/. I think it causes some executions before time.